# Gaussian measures on non-separable spaces

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, ag.algebraic-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

Let $X$ be a topological affine space which is neither separable nor metrizable. There are plenty of trivial Gaussian measures: each Dirac point-mass $\delta_x$ are the Gaussian measure with zero covariance and mean $x \in X$

When does a topological affine space $X$ admit a non-trivial Gaussian measure? Namely, one whose support is the whole space $X$? One can always construct a Gaussian measure supported on a finite-dimensional subspace of $X$, such as a line.

Is local convexity of $X$ a sufficient criterion for there to exist a Gaussian measure supported on all of $X$?

Comment: A measure concentrated in a line... is that considered non-trivial?

Comment: why is there an algebraic-geometry tag? (it's not a complaint, it's curiosity)

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: good point. We can always construct measures which has support on a finite-dimensional subspace of $X$. Let's add the condition that the support of the measure is the whole space.

Comment: @Jacob Bell: I suspect that algebraic geometers are the mathematicians who think the most about general categories of spaces like topological affine spaces. I put the tag to get their input. 

Comment: Topological affine space.  If I fix a point in it (for the origin), then is it a topological vector space?

Comment: What does "gaussian measure" mean if there are no continuous linear functionals on the space?

Comment: @Gerald (my apologies for misspelling your name before), a topological affine space is a topological vector space with the origin forgotten. Thankfully, the situation you hypothesize never occurs: there is always the zero functional. In that case, the only centered Gaussian measure is the Dirac point-mass concentrated on the origin. 

Comment: The definition is still unknown to me.  In a locally convex space I do know what is a Gaussian measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a paper by H. Sato, [Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-36/issue-none/Gaussian-measure-on-a-Banach-space-and-abstract-Wiener-measure/nmj/1118797795.full)

proving that 1) a Gaussian measure on a reflexive Banach space is always concentrated on a separable subspace, and 2) the canonical Gaussian cylinder measure of a nonseparable Hubert space cannot be extended to a $\sigma$-additive measure in any Banach space.

Comment: Thanks, @Anatoly Kochubei! Is is the case that in the non-separable setting, Gaussian measures are always concentrated on separable subspaces? It would seem reasonable that the answer is yes, which provides a negative answer to my original question. I was mulling over your second fact last night (the canonical Gaussian cylinder-set measure cannot be extended to a genuine measure), and am glad to see the reference. I'll take a look at Satô's paper and let you know if I've got any questions.

Comment: Indeed, this does answer the question. The Corollary to Theorem 2 states that there is no admissible norm on a non-separable Hilbert space. Since the support of the measure in affine space $X$ is the closure of the Cameron-Martin space corresponding to the covariance operator, the support of the measure must be separable. Consequently, there can be no Gaussian measure with full support in a non-separable affine space. Cheers.